# Error 502 accessing nextcloud via docker with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

### Heyo!

## Update: I figured it out and added my answer.

I'm currently in the process of learning docker and I've written a docker-compose file that should launch nginx, gitea, **nextcloud** and route them all via domain name as a reverse proxy.

All is going well except for with *nextcloud*. I can access it via localhost:3001 but not via the nginx reverse proxy. **All is well with gitea**, it works both ways.

The error I'm getting is:

```
nginx_proxy     | 2018/08/10 00:17:34 [error] 8#8: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: cloud.example.ca, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.4:3001/", host: "cloud.example.ca"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx_proxy
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    volumes: 
// Here I'm swapping out my default.conf for the container's by mounting my 
directory over theirs.
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - proxy

  nextcloud_db:
    container_name: nextcloud_db
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud_db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/cloud_db_root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/cloud_db_pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: devcloud
      MYSQL_USER: devcloud
    secrets:
      - cloud_db_root
      - cloud_db_pass
    networks:
      - database

  gitea_db:
    container_name: gitea_db
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - gitea_db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/cloud_db_root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/cloud_db_pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gitea
      MYSQL_USER: gitea
    secrets:
      - cloud_db_root
      - cloud_db_pass
    networks:
      - database

  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 3001:80
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    networks:
      - proxy
      - database

  gitea:
    container_name: gitea
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    environment:
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - gitea:/data
    ports:
      -  3000:3000
      -  22:22
    networks:
      - proxy
      - database

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  nextcloud_db:
  gitea:
  gitea_db:

networks:
  proxy:
  database:

secrets:
  cloud_db_pass:
    file: cloud_db_pass.txt
  cloud_db_root:
    file: cloud_db_root.txt
```

My default.conf that gets mounted into /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
upstream nextcloud {
         server nextcloud:3001;
}

upstream gitea {
         server gitea:3000;
}

server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name cloud.example.ca;

       location / {
                proxy_pass http://nextcloud;
                }
}

server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name git.example.ca;

       location / {
                proxy_pass http://gitea;
                }
}
```

I of course have my hosts file setup to route the domains to localhost. I've done a bit of googling but nothing I've found so far seems to align with what I'm running into. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, one does not simply reverse proxy to port 80 with nextcloud. It's just not allowed. I have it deployed and working great with a certificate over 443! :)